# How to get the index of the Flux.fromIterable

Tags: java, mono, flux, iterable, flatmap

I searched for a long time but couldn't find anything in this topic which can help me in this situation. I have the following code:

```
return Flux.fromIterable(listOfObjects)
            .parallel()
            .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .flatMap(this::getDataResponse)
            .flatMap(dataResponse-> this.afterCheckVariables(dataResponse, {currentElementOfTheList}))
        .sequential();
```

I want to set a variable in every dataResponse based on the current element of the list. Is it possible?
If i could get the index or the current element of the list, it would be great.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

May I find a solution, if you have better approach please let me know.

The solution was the following:

I needed to create other method which gives back the current element of the List.
So my code changed like this:

```
return Flux.fromIterable(listOfObjects)
            .parallel()
            .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .flatMap(this::getReq)
            .flatMap(requestObj -> this.getDataResponse(requestObj)
            .flatMap(dataResponse-> this.afterCheckVariables(dataResponse,requestObj)))
        .sequential();
```

The getReq method looks like this:

```
private Mono<ObjectOfList> getReq (ObjectOfList request){
        return Mono.just(request);
    }
```